# xampp question. - is installed as a windows service?

Tags: xampp

[image]

Hello
I'm runnding xampp with administrator mode.
But I see some red x in service boxes.
What is this?
When I put cursor on it, it shows 'is installed as a windows service?".

1. What is this?
2. Is it needed to run xampp?

I am kind of worried since it's red x so something goes wrong or some error are here or not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just install the JDK.

1. Download the Java SE Development Kit, please click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html#GUID-A7E27B90-A28D-4237-9383-A58B416071CA)
2. If you use windows 64bit please pick Windows x64.
3. If you use windows 32bit please pick Windows x86.
4. If you use not windows please choose another. After that, please install on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall xampp and again install it but don't in "C:\Program Files\xampp" This problem is cause by windows permission so it is better to install xampp on any other path.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is **merely** telling you that these server programs are **not installed as services. There's nothing to worry about.**
2. **No, there's no need to install these as services**, and certainly Xampp doesn't require you to run them in any way but just provides you with the means of controlling their running status. It's a matter of choice. You can run these as regular programs or as services. Buy default Xampp installs them as regular programs, but if you click on the X it offers you the option to install them as services, which is entirely up to you.